# Why data = copy.deepcopy(G) matters in Karger min cut algorithm?

Tags: python, min

Here is the code to compute the min cut posted here [karger min cut algorithm in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825200/karger-min-cut-algorithm-in-python-2-7). Without data = copy.deepcopy(G), the efficiency to find the min cut is not good. Can anybody explain why? Thanks.

```
import random, copy
data = open("***.txt","r")
G = {}
for line in data:
    lst = [int(s) for s in line.split()]
    G[lst[0]] = lst[1:]   

def choose_random_key(G):
    v1 = random.choice(list(G.keys()))
    v2 = random.choice(list(G[v1]))
    return v1, v2

def karger(G):
    length = []
    while len(G) > 2:
        v1, v2 = choose_random_key(G)
        G[v1].extend(G[v2])
        for x in G[v2]:
            G[x].remove(v2)
            G[x].append(v1) 
        while v1 in G[v1]:
            G[v1].remove(v1)
        del G[v2]
    for key in G.keys():
        length.append(len(G[key]))
    return length[0]

def operation(n):
    i = 0
    count = 10000   
    while i < n:
        data = copy.deepcopy(G)
        min_cut = karger(data)
        if min_cut < count:
            count = min_cut
        i = i + 1
    return count


print(operation(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

`data = G` and `karger(data)` doesn't duplicate dictionary and `karger(data)` would use original `G` dictionary. But `karger` changes values in `data` so automatically it would change values in original dictionary. So next executions of `karger(data)` would use dictionary with different values.

Remove `deepcopy` and add `print(data)` before `karger(data)` and you see different values in `data`.

Comment: Thanks, furas. Only the deepcopy works here to keep data unchanged. Copy.copy did not work here either.